# modify column value if condition in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below values in table, and need to set valid_values =6 when found >6

```
  ID        VALUE           VALID_VALUES
---------- --------------- ---------------------------------------------
       555 OFF              OFF,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

So after change desired output would be as below,

```
SQL> /

    FIS_ID VALUE           VALID_VALUES
---------- --------------- ---------------------------------------------

   417     OFF             OFF,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,6
```

Comment: You should seriously consider _not_ storing CSV data in your tables like this, especially if you plan to update/modify it.  Instead, get each valid value onto a separate row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to split and aggregate; instead you can use a regular expression to find either 2-or-more-digit numbers (i.e. `[1-9]\d+`) or 1-digit values higher than 6 (i.e. `[789]`) and could include leading zeroes if these may appear in your data set (since you are storing numbers as text):

```sql
SELECT id,
       value,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         valid_values,
         '0*[1-9]\d+|0*[789]',
         '6'
       ) AS valid_values
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, VALUE, VALID_VALUES ) AS
SELECT 555, 'OFF', 'OFF,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 666, 'OFF', 'OFF,1,2,3,4,5,6,42,05,0123' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
>  ID | VALUE | VALID_VALUES           
> --: | :---- | :----------------------
> 555 | OFF   | OFF,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,6
> 666 | OFF   | OFF,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,05,6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9a36e1af7b31ddc5c6fb02965d812672)*

Answer (score 0):

You need to split, replace and aggregate as follows:

```
Select id, value, 
       Listagg(case when to_number(vals default null on conversion error) is not null 
                    then case when to_number(vals) > 6 then 6 else vals end 
              else vals end) Within group (order by lvl) as valid_values
 From
(Select id, value, 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.valid_values, '[^,]+', 1, column_value ) ) , ',' ) as vals, 
        column_value as lvl
   from your_table t,
       TABLE(CAST(MULTISET(
             SELECT level as lvl
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.valid_value, '[^,]+' )
            AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIS  ) v
 ) group by id, value;
```

Answer (score 0):

For this solution, you need to split using LAG analytic function, before replacing and aggregating as below :

```sql
select ID, VALUE
  , listagg(
      case when regexp_like(separate_value, '^\d+$') 
        then case when separate_value > 6 
              then '6' 
              else separate_value 
            end
        else separate_value 
      end
      , ',') within group (order by lvl) VALID_VALUES
from (
select ID, VALUE
    , lvl, substr(VALID_VALUES, lag(pos, 1, 0)over(order by lvl)+1, pos - lag(pos, 1, 0)over(order by lvl)-1) separate_value
from (
  select ID, VALUE, VALID_VALUES||','VALID_VALUES, level lvl, instr(VALID_VALUES||',', ',', 1, level)pos
  from your_table
  connect by level <= length(VALID_VALUES||',')-length(replace(VALID_VALUES||',', ','))
  )
)
group by ID, VALUE
;
```